# Can I add a translation language on a drupal site using British Sign Language?

Tags: drupal, translation

I want to create a drupal website which will be in English but with a translation in the British sign language.  Is this possible?

Comment: You need sign language for something that's printed?  

Besides that, check http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads for information on localization.

Comment: Can you point to an existing site with content in this language? I"m really curious what this look like.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I posted this question before fully researching what I actually wanted.  I've since realised that having a translation in British sign language means putting up a video!  Not showing any written text, so my question is totally misleading.sorry if I confused anyone. For an example of what I mean see the website http://www.becomingvisible.co.uk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Drupal core Locale module, you can add a custom language for British sign language (code is sgn-UK or bfi) from the "*Administer > Languages > Add Language*" page. You can then use this language like any other and [build a multilingual Drupal site](http://drupal.org/node/133977).